# Check if page title already exists in a custom taxonomy category (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type called 'movie' and custom taxonomy called 'genre'.

The genre custom taxonomy has several categories, such as 'western', 'action', animation' etc.

What I am trying to do is check if a post already exists in one of the custom categories, before running this function...

```
wp_insert_post( $args);
```

So for example, if I go to create a new movie post called **Terminator** and want to put it in the 'action' custom category, I need a condition that checks if a post called **Terminator** already exists in that 'action' category before running the `wp_insert_post()` function.

I know about this...

```
$post_id = post_exists( 'Terminator' );
if (!$post_id) {
    // 
}
```

...but that only checks for a duplicate post across all posts, and so isn't very helpful.

Can this even be done in WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WP_Query` to search in previous `CTPs`:

```
$post_args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'movie',
    'post_title' => 'terminator',
    'tax_query'  => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'genre',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'action',
        ),
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $post_args );

if( ! $query->have_posts() ) {
    $args = array(
        .......
    );

    wp_insert_post( $args);
}
```